# How can I connect to the Share&Charge test backend

Tags: shareandcharge

I'm trying to integrate our MSP backend with the Share&Charge search server in order to start and stop charge operations. Where can I get an API key and the address of the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the documentation on how to connect to the Open Charging Network (OCN) can be found in the developer resources section of our web page https://shareandcharge.com/developer-resources/

instructions on how to connect to the test network can be found here: https://shareandcharge.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OCN/pages/409370650/Connecting+a+service+Test+Network